# how to customize the google marker cluster renderer?

Tags: android, google-maps

In my application I have put more than 50K markers on google maps. I want to customize the marker cluster renderer. The number displayed on marker wasn't correct it displays wrong number it haven't contains the number pins that it displays on the marker. Please help me to solve this problem. I am using the following code to cluster the markers:

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.503186, -0.126446), 10));

// Initialize the manager with the context and the map.
// (Activity extends context, so we can pass 'this' in the constructor.)
mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, mMap);
mClusterManager.setRenderer(new MyClusterRenderer<MyItem>(this, mMap,mClusterManager));

// Point the map's listeners at the listeners implemented by the cluster
// manager.
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

addItems();
```

Function to Add Items

```
private void addItems() {
    for (int i = 0; i < placesCoordinates.size(); i++) {
        MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(placesCoordinates.get(i).getLat(), placesCoordinates.get(i).getLng());
        mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
    }
}
```

Data set of coordinates:

```
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.763557,-73.972302,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.762123,-73.974824,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.722165,-73.999198,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.758037,-73.97699 ,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.750718,-73.988592,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.763502,-73.97395 ,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.757155,-73.978499,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.720076,-73.997571,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.721643,-74.000222,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.752877,-73.99622 ,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.743386,-73.993546,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.7403,     -73.995,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.706925,-74.004398,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.7225,   -73.988314,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.721334,-73.988946,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.760245,-73.984354,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.711741,-74.008775,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.734311,-73.990107,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.760964,-73.968482,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.762424,-73.973481,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.762424,-73.973481,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.73487,-73.991409 ,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.761488,-73.967123,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.795354,-73.931178,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.784815,-73.979711,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.739037,-73.995811,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.734279,-73.990288,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.724569,-73.996485,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.741841,-73.992895,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.739293,-73.994109,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.725744,-73.996881,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.712914,-74.007793,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.760388,-73.98506 ,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.72562,-73.999731 ,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.735868,-74.004994,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.742092,-73.991766,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.758243,-73.984917,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.738153,-73.989673,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.722836,-73.999158,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.741049,-73.991926,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.762424,-73.973481,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.73487,-73.991409 ,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.761488,-73.967123,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.795354,-73.931178,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.784815,-73.979711,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.739037,-73.995811,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.734279,-73.990288,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.724569,-73.996485,false));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.741841,-73.992895,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.739293,-73.994109,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.725744,-73.996881,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.712914,-74.007793,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.760388,-73.98506 ,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.72562,-73.999731 ,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.735868,-74.004994,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.742092,-73.991766,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.758243,-73.984917,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.738153,-73.989673,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.722836,-73.999158,true));
    placesCoordinates.add(new Places(40.741049,-73.991926,true));
```

Comment: Can you provide an example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @not_a_bot Thanks, I have resolved this issue Now. After spending a lot of time on debugging I cam to know that ,there nothing wrong with numbering of cluster marker, the problem is with my data set.

Comment: @not_a_bot can solve my problem I have post it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075153/how-to-add-layout-over-google-maps/32076381#32076381

Comment: If you were able to solve this issue on your own, I'd recommend posting the solution as an answer and accepting it so that anyone who sees this question will know it's been resolved.

Comment: @not_a_bot yeh sure i'll post it as a answer. I dont know about this feature of Stackoverflow. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a complete day on debugging I came to know that the problem is not with cluster marker numbering, actually the problem is with my data set. It contains similar coordinates multiple times.