# How to add layout over google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

In my application there is a google map, When user clicks on a pin a specific layout will display exactly like SncakBar, Layout contains some Buttons and TextViews. Please help me how can I add layout over google map.
XML file of Main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="12dp"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <!--&lt;!&ndash; android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"&ndash;&gt;-->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:name="com.example.muhammad.shopplus.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a extra layout at the bottom of the screen by using Framelayout or inside of your current layout. At the beginning, it will be invisible. When user press somewhere, it will be visible at the bottom. This is my suggestions. You can try if it works.